# Gradually or smoothly change object size (Checkboxlist)?

Tags: c#, timer, size, checklistbox

C# question

Here is what I am trying to do. When I click a button, I want the checkboxlist to smoothly change from say (200,10) to (200,100) in size. I am successful at getting to size to change instantaneously, but I want it to look smooth.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.Height < 100)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Size = new Size(checkedListBox1.Size.Width, checkedListBox1.Size.Height + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I have used this coding to move objects smoothly, but never to change sizes.

So when you run this code, the box just flickers and it seems like its trying to change size, but it doesn't, and the loop never ends.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [IntegralHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.integralheight.aspx) to `false` to that the box can be a height that is not a multiple of the item height.

For the flickering, you should probably [double-buffer the form](https://web.archive.org/web/20121123031717/http://www.bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.htm) which contains this control.

Comment: Thanks Dark, 

I added checkedListBox1.IntegralHeight = false; into the mix and that cleared it right up. Works like a charm.

Now I'll see about that double-buffer.

Comment: @Dark Falcon What about DataGridViewColumn? Can we make it change size smoothly?

Comment: @DinoVelić, there are no limitations on the column width except for `MinimumWidth`. Double buffering would still apply in the same way.